# Странный текст уведомления

Tags: поддержка, уведомления

[image: удаленоудаленоудалено]

Почему текст уведомления

> удаленоудаленоудалено

Ссылка такая: [Не проходит авторизация на форуме. В чем причина?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523100/%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be/523292#523292)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разобрался. Не заметил, что автор [попортил вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/523100/3).

Comment: Пометьте свой ответ как принятый, пожалуйста. Чтобы он визуально отличался в списке вопросов от тех, что ещё требуют внимания.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, система позволяет принять свой ответ не раньше чем через двое суток после публикации вопроса, так что пока не могу.

Comment: Извините, забыл об этом ограничении.